# Sending cLog entries into a database from Talend Runtime

Tags: log4j2, talend, karaf

I'm configuring Talend ESB (OpenSource) and I want to be able to redirect the logging, such as from the Camel Log components etc., to a database.

I've tried editing the `org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` file to add a JDBCAppender, but when karaf imports this file I get a message *"Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender for element JDBC... No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.jog4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender"*

Is this likely to be because the right appender classes aren't registered in Karaf, in which case can someone point me where I can find the feature/bundle I need, or is there something more subtle going on that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is to find your bundle and to install it in karaf

```
feature:list|grep -i camel
```

above command shows you which jdbc compenets aren't installed yet and you can install them in karaf using `feature:install camel-jdbc` try this.
[image]